# Frameset makes dropdown invisible

Tags: drop-down-menu, z-index, frameset, invisible

I use framesets (I know, that is very very bad :)) and that works for me, but I have one little problem: the frameset does not  allow me to see the dropdown box that I have made. **It just shows one list item and the other 4 items are invisible**. If I enlarge the frameset, then it will show up, but that is not a solution because the site won't be the way I want it to be (it goes to the bottom).

This is the frameset: `frameset id="f" border="0" rows="50"` and this is the css of the dropdown menu:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
```

I have tried `overflow` etcetera, but it didn't work. Can someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that this happens, because this is a frameset we are talking of.... A thing used before Christ...

So yeah, my answer is solved by my own.